# Unable to change data type into date

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I exported a column that represents the date in the format of yyyymmdd into Power BI. However, when I tried to change the data type to "Date", it shows an error. Currently the yyyymmdd is being read as a whole number but I would like to change it. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried changing the data type to "Date" but it shows as an error.

The expected result would be where the data type is changed from "whole number" to "Date"

Answer (score 0):

Transform your column, using:

```
= Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"MyColumn", each Date.FromText(Text.From(_)), type date}})
```